# Javascript Console outputting different value then on text

Tags: javascript, html

This was very hard to describe in the title so I hope I do a better job here.
So what my code does is calculate some values using the given values. the expression is `BlackEggsAt100 * ((1 + RebirthPower)^180)` Where `BlackEggsAt100` is a given value in a textarea and the same for `RebirthPower` 
I have 2 textareas, one with the id of `level` and the other with `power`
I am using the example values `12820` for the BlackEggsAt100 and `0.025` for the RebirthPower

I have tried:
Switching browsers (Edge, Google Chrome)
using Math.Ceil and Math.trunc

```js
var LVL100 = document.getElementById('level').value;  // Grabs Value from Level 100 Box 
var Power = document.getElementById('Power').value;   // Grabs Value from Rebirth Power Box
var Added = 1+Power;
var exponented = Math.pow(Added, 180);             // Gets the power of the Rebirth % and 180
var OutputVal = LVL100*exponented;                    // Multiplies the black eggs at level 100 by the exponented value
var Output = document.getElementById('Output');
Output.innerHTML =  OutputVal
```

I expect the value `1091902.337` or `1091902.3374758072` to be added to the Output div, but what I actually get is `2.0094474710243997e+184` if you were to try this in the Google Chrome javascript console (Ctrl+Shift+I) and entered

```js
var Added = 1+0.025
var exponented = Math.pow(Added, 180) 
console.log(12820*exponented)
```

When using the code above i receive the expected output of `1091902.3374758072`

Comment: HTML values are Strings. You need to cast those Strings to Numbers, like `var Power = document.getElementById('Power').value;`

Comment: @StackSlave Correct, though in this specific example, `LVL100` is actually alright as a string; it's only used by the `*` operator, which will coerce it to `Number` regardless. However, `Power` is going to be a problem. For example, `var Added = 1+"10"` is `"110"`, **not** `11`. Also, just as a style note, it's general convention for variable names to start with a lowercase letter, and uppercase be reserved for classes and constructors.

Comment: @StackSlave In your edited comment, you forgot the `+`. I believe what you meant was `var Power = +document.getElementById('Power').value;`, seeing as that was what you had pre-edit. Just clarifying for OP.

Comment: @TylerRoper This also worked as well at the answer below that I marked as correct, which would be better practice to use in the future? Thanks for the help!

Comment: They're the same, but `Number(...)` is always a bit more clear to those who may not be familiar with unary `+` operators. Also, adding becomes a bit ugly. For example, `+"10" + +"10"` isn't as nice as, say, `Number(10) + Number(10)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your value `LVL100` or `Power` is in string which cause problem. So for that you can do this like convert them to number and then perform your calculation.

```
var LVL100 = Number(document.getElementById('level').value); 
var Power = Number(document.getElementById('Power').value);
var Added = 1+Power;
var exponented = Math.pow(Added, 180);             
var OutputVal = LVL100*exponented;                     
var Output = document.getElementById('Output');
Output.innerHTML =  OutputVal
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but which would be better to use in the future `+document.getElementById('Power').value;` or `Power = Number(document.getElementById('Power').value);`